# Why settings for IK-Constraint are different for mirrored bones?

Tags: rigging, armature

Please, explain me what is going on here. IK for arms is good, but legs give me headache.

You can switch between **Rest** and **Pose** modes to see the problem appears. Changing *Pole Angle* to 180 deg for Leg.R solves the issue, but hey why Arms work without this tweaking and Legs are not?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One big influence on this issue is bone roll. You can check the roll of a bone by selecting it in edit mode, pressing "N" to open the shelf and looking under "Transform."
[image: bone roll shelf]
If your pole target bones (knee bones) don't have the same roll as your leg bones, it can get wonky. You can reset the roll of your bones by selecting them and pressing CTRL+N . Recalculating along the global Z axis can work well in this case.

Comment: Recalculated bone roll is 0.01 and IK for Legs is still strange.
http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=111103

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem follow the below steps:

1. Switch to Pose Mode
2. Select all bones with <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Hit the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>
4. Write `Select Pose as Rest Pose` as shown below

[image]

Comment: I want my legs to be on the same level both in Pose and Rest modes. So if I apply uncorrect pose as rest it will not help me at all.

Comment: applying pose as rest pose will make the legs to be on the same level in Pose and rest modes.

Comment: Here is what I'm talking about http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=111109
All was done accordingly with your algorithm. Maybe you can provide proper Blend?